# How to create a File+Folder Tree View via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jstree, filetree

I'm trying to create a way to view CSV file that contains details about a folder and sub folders on a physical drive.

Here's the CSV file:

```
Volume,Path,Name,Size,Ext,Last modified,Description
"Music","/All Rock Music/All Rock Albums/Rock Album","01. Track 1.mp3",4274491,"mp3",2019-05-23 17:35:23,""
```

I've converted this csv for javascript array with papa parse [plugin](https://www.papaparse.com/).
Now I found this [plugin](https://github.com/jqueryfiletree/jqueryfiletree) to create a tree structure for viewing of the file. Since I don't want a server so, the php won't run.

On their github page, it says:

> You can create a custom connector script to extend the functionality
>   of the file tree. The easiest way to do this is probably by modifying
>   one of the scripts supplied in the download. If you want to start from
>   scratch, your script should accept one POST variable (dir) and output
>   an unsorted list in the following format:

```html
<ul class="jqueryFileTree">
        <li class="directory collapsed"><a href="#" rel="/this/folder/">Folder Name</a></li>
        (additional folders here)
        <li class="file ext_txt"><a href="#" rel="/this/folder/filename.txt">filename.txt</a></li>
        (additional files here)
</ul>
```

Please could you suggest how to use this plugin without the PHP?

Also, there's an alternative to this filetree plugin.. Check it out [here](https://www.jstree.com/)

It requires my html structure to be:

```html
<div id="jstree">
    <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
    <ul>
      <li>Root node 1
        <ul>
          <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
          <li>Child node 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Root node 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

My file_data_array is: `data[i][1]` where

- `data` is an array of all the files in the directory/sub-directory.
- `i` is the iterator.
- `1` is file path as per this csv header:

  1. Volume,
  2. Path,
  3. Name,
  4. Size,
  5. Ext,
  6. Last modified,
  7. Description

Any idea how I can create a file tree with [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/) with directories and their files and sub directories, using the above array?

EDIT:
I found this [PHP script](https://github.com/vakata/jstree-php-demos/blob/master/filebrowser/index.php) that generates the UL list on the server side. Could someone suggest how to create the same list in javascript for the client side? I have a csv file input, and so don't need ajax request.

code:

```php
<?php
ini_set('open_basedir', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
class fs
{
    protected $base = null;
    protected function real($path) {
        $temp = realpath($path);
        if(!$temp) { throw new Exception('Path does not exist: ' . $path); }
        if($this->base && strlen($this->base)) {
            if(strpos($temp, $this->base) !== 0) { throw new Exception('Path is not inside base ('.$this->base.'): ' . $temp); }
        }
        return $temp;
    }
    protected function path($id) {
        $id = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $id);
        $id = trim($id, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
        $id = $this->real($this->base . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $id);
        return $id;
    }
    protected function id($path) {
        $path = $this->real($path);
        $path = substr($path, strlen($this->base));
        $path = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', $path);
        $path = trim($path, '/');
        return strlen($path) ? $path : '/';
    }
    public function __construct($base) {
        $this->base = $this->real($base);
        if(!$this->base) { throw new Exception('Base directory does not exist'); }
    }
    public function lst($id, $with_root = false) {
        $dir = $this->path($id);
        $lst = @scandir($dir);
        if(!$lst) { throw new Exception('Could not list path: ' . $dir); }
        $res = array();
        foreach($lst as $item) {
            if($item == '.' || $item == '..' || $item === null) { continue; }
            $tmp = preg_match('([^ a-zа-я-_0-9.]+)ui', $item);
            if($tmp === false || $tmp === 1) { continue; }
            if(is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item)) {
                $res[] = array('text' => $item, 'children' => true,  'id' => $this->id($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item), 'icon' => 'folder');
            }
            else {
                $res[] = array('text' => $item, 'children' => false, 'id' => $this->id($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item), 'type' => 'file', 'icon' => 'file file-'.substr($item, strrpos($item,'.') + 1));
            }
        }
        if($with_root && $this->id($dir) === '/') {
            $res = array(array('text' => basename($this->base), 'children' => $res, 'id' => '/', 'icon'=>'folder', 'state' => array('opened' => true, 'disabled' => true)));
        }
        return $res;
    }
    public function data($id) {
        if(strpos($id, ":")) {
            $id = array_map(array($this, 'id'), explode(':', $id));
            return array('type'=>'multiple', 'content'=> 'Multiple selected: ' . implode(' ', $id));
        }
        $dir = $this->path($id);
        if(is_dir($dir)) {
            return array('type'=>'folder', 'content'=> $id);
        }
        if(is_file($dir)) {
            $ext = strpos($dir, '.') !== FALSE ? substr($dir, strrpos($dir, '.') + 1) : '';
            $dat = array('type' => $ext, 'content' => '');
            switch($ext) {
                case 'txt':
                case 'text':
                case 'md':
                case 'js':
                case 'json':
                case 'css':
                case 'html':
                case 'htm':
                case 'xml':
                case 'c':
                case 'cpp':
                case 'h':
                case 'sql':
                case 'log':
                case 'py':
                case 'rb':
                case 'htaccess':
                case 'php':
                    $dat['content'] = file_get_contents($dir);
                    break;
                case 'jpg':
                case 'jpeg':
                case 'gif':
                case 'png':
                case 'bmp':
                    $dat['content'] = 'data:'.finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $dir).';base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($dir));
                    break;
                default:
                    $dat['content'] = 'File not recognized: '.$this->id($dir);
                    break;
            }
            return $dat;
        }
        throw new Exception('Not a valid selection: ' . $dir);
    }
    public function create($id, $name, $mkdir = false) {
        $dir = $this->path($id);
        if(preg_match('([^ a-zа-я-_0-9.]+)ui', $name) || !strlen($name)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid name: ' . $name);
        }
        if($mkdir) {
            mkdir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name);
        }
        else {
            file_put_contents($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name, '');
        }
        return array('id' => $this->id($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name));
    }
    public function rename($id, $name) {
        $dir = $this->path($id);
        if($dir === $this->base) {
            throw new Exception('Cannot rename root');
        }
        if(preg_match('([^ a-zа-я-_0-9.]+)ui', $name) || !strlen($name)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid name: ' . $name);
        }
        $new = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $dir);
        array_pop($new);
        array_push($new, $name);
        $new = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $new);
        if($dir !== $new) {
            if(is_file($new) || is_dir($new)) { throw new Exception('Path already exists: ' . $new); }
            rename($dir, $new);
        }
        return array('id' => $this->id($new));
    }
    public function remove($id) {
        $dir = $this->path($id);
        if($dir === $this->base) {
            throw new Exception('Cannot remove root');
        }
        if(is_dir($dir)) {
            foreach(array_diff(scandir($dir), array(".", "..")) as $f) {
                $this->remove($this->id($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $f));
            }
            rmdir($dir);
        }
        if(is_file($dir)) {
            unlink($dir);
        }
        return array('status' => 'OK');
    }
    public function move($id, $par) {
        $dir = $this->path($id);
        $par = $this->path($par);
        $new = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $dir);
        $new = array_pop($new);
        $new = $par . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new;
        rename($dir, $new);
        return array('id' => $this->id($new));
    }
    public function copy($id, $par) {
        $dir = $this->path($id);
        $par = $this->path($par);
        $new = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $dir);
        $new = array_pop($new);
        $new = $par . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new;
        if(is_file($new) || is_dir($new)) { throw new Exception('Path already exists: ' . $new); }
        if(is_dir($dir)) {
            mkdir($new);
            foreach(array_diff(scandir($dir), array(".", "..")) as $f) {
                $this->copy($this->id($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $f), $this->id($new));
            }
        }
        if(is_file($dir)) {
            copy($dir, $new);
        }
        return array('id' => $this->id($new));
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['operation'])) {
    $fs = new fs(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'root' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    try {
        $rslt = null;
        switch($_GET['operation']) {
            case 'get_node':
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? $_GET['id'] : '/';
                $rslt = $fs->lst($node, (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] === '#'));
                break;
            case "get_content":
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? $_GET['id'] : '/';
                $rslt = $fs->data($node);
                break;
            case 'create_node':
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? $_GET['id'] : '/';
                $rslt = $fs->create($node, isset($_GET['text']) ? $_GET['text'] : '', (!isset($_GET['type']) || $_GET['type'] !== 'file'));
                break;
            case 'rename_node':
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? $_GET['id'] : '/';
                $rslt = $fs->rename($node, isset($_GET['text']) ? $_GET['text'] : '');
                break;
            case 'delete_node':
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? $_GET['id'] : '/';
                $rslt = $fs->remove($node);
                break;
            case 'move_node':
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? $_GET['id'] : '/';
                $parn = isset($_GET['parent']) && $_GET['parent'] !== '#' ? $_GET['parent'] : '/';
                $rslt = $fs->move($node, $parn);
                break;
            case 'copy_node':
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? $_GET['id'] : '/';
                $parn = isset($_GET['parent']) && $_GET['parent'] !== '#' ? $_GET['parent'] : '/';
                $rslt = $fs->copy($node, $parn);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Unsupported operation: ' . $_GET['operation']);
                break;
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($rslt);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 500 Server Error');
        header('Status:  500 Server Error');
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    die();
}
?>
```